# The meaning of "you are a smash"

Tags: phrases

Ok, in the TV series Glee season3 episode 21, I came across this sentence: `you were a smash.` From the context, it might mean `you were wonderful` or something. Then I looked this up online, I found `smash` means `sex` in Urban Dictonary, which is definitely not what I was looking for. So is there a phrase `you are a smash`? What does it mean?

well, then I found this [smash, slang](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/smash), which says that `smash` can mean `a successful thing, especially a movie`, so can you use it to describe people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Green's *Dictionary of Slang* lists numerous meanings for *smash*, but the one that appears relevant is:-

> **smash** n. a great success, a 'smash' hit

from which you can get the adjectives *smashing* or (if you like) *smashtastic*.

Other meanings are possible, but if your context suggests a compliment, that's the only one that could apply.

See also [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/smash), meaning (6):-

> *Informal* A resounding success: *The play was a smash on Broadway*

**Edit:** per your edit, certainly. One could be a *smash* on the stage, at a party, at some sporting event or just generally.

Comment: Note that you could say "You were a smash." or predict "You will be a smash." but you wouldn't normally say "You are a smash." (as your title states). There has to be feedback from an audience in order to be a smash. I suppose you could be backstage and hear the immediate response of the audience, and say, "You are a smash."

Comment: As Brian said, "smash" is slang for success.  I just wanted to add that, though it _can_ be applied generally, it's typically used in conjunction with a performance of some sort. (The person who was a "smash" at the party, e.g., would almost assuredly be one who drew a lot of favorable attention to himself.)

Comment: @J.R., and JLG, good points.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, I also want to add that although you can use "you were/are a smash" to mean "you were/are a success", you can't generalize it and say "smashing" to mean "success".  Not saying you would, but if I was the asker and told just that, I would automatically assume that I could use "smashing" in the same way.

It's funny and I don't know why, but saying "you were/are smashing" would be closer to saying "you were/are great" or "excellent".

I've heard many people also say "that was a smashing success", but then obviously you can't say "that was a smashing smash".  That would just sound strange.